# Update String in JArray in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm trying to update the `status` of `User 2` to `DONE`

I got this JSON array

```
[
    {
        "id":"YWauEwCUIe",
        "name":"User 1",
        "status":"DONE"
    },
    {
        "id":"JgwCjgvU5b",
        "name":"User 2",
        "status":"WAIT"
    }
]
```

I tried with this code, but it not going to work.

```
mUsers[0][status] = "DONE";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try `mUsers[0]["status"] = "DONE";` instead? It would help if you could provide a [mcve] rather than just a line of code, and explain exactly what happens with what you've tried, rather than just "it not going to work".

Comment: I tried with `['status']` and now try `["status"]` and it worked. BTW Thanks.

Comment: Single quotes are for literal values of `char` type, whereas double quotes are for `string`. That's why double quotes work and single quotes don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `[0]` you are changing the status of "User 1"
For "User 2" you need to use `[1]` and also write "status" between quotation marks

```
 mUsers[1]["status"] = "DONE";
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the name status as a String in the JSON-Array like this:

```
mUsers[0]["status"] = "DONE";
```